# Power BI Dax - Trying to break circular dependency after one attempt

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to figure out ancestor bloodline in data I have. I feel like there is something I am missing to make this work. This data wouldn't change so not sure if I am missing something I can write in the power query editor when loading / refreshing the data.

While technically it is circular in fields it never going to return the same row it is currently in and the first generation is hard number making a starting point. I only want to reference the mother and father to calculate the child's bloodline. The first generation is a basic IF() statement. Below is as far as I can get before hitting the circular dependency error. I have tried a few things to break it thinking its going to loop.

Logic is:

1. Each blood is 100% for 1st generations based on their birthplace then it is ((mother blood + father blood) / 2) for each generation after that. I found I can use PATHITEM() to isolate the type of blood but errors with a circular dependency. (This is where I can't figure out how to reference the mother / father to do the calculation.) If I take this part out I get the image below working for 1st generation and correct mother / father for second generation.

```
Asisa Blood = 
VAR current_id = 'Sheet1'[ID]
VAR current_gen = 'Sheet1'[Generation]
VAR current_blood = 'Sheet1'[Birthplace]
VAR current_mother_blood = 
    PATHITEM(
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCT('Sheet1'[Mother's Blood Mix]),
        FILTER(
            ALLNOBLANKROW('Sheet1'[ID]),
            'Sheet1'[ID] = current_id
        ),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Sheet1')
    ),1,INTEGER)
VAR current_father_blood = 
    PATHITEM(
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCT('Sheet1'[Father's Blood Mix]),
        FILTER(
            ALLNOBLANKROW('Sheet1'[ID]),
            'Sheet1'[ID] = current_id
        ),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Sheet1')
    ),1,INTEGER)
VAR gen1_value = 100

RETURN
    IF(AND(LOWER(current_gen) = "1",LOWER(current_blood) = "asisa"),
    gen1_value,
    ((current_mother_blood + current_father_blood)/2)
    )
```

2. Blood Mix concatenates the four blood types into one field for easy look up in next step.

```
Blood mix = 
VAR current__id = 'Sheet1'[ID]
VAR current_blood_a = 'Sheet1'[Asisa Blood]
VAR current_blood_b = 'Sheet1'[Africa Blood]
VAR current_blood_c = 'Sheet1'[Europe Blood]
VAR current_blood_d = 'Sheet1'[North America Blood] 

RETURN
    current_blood_a & "|" & current_blood_b & "|" & current_blood_c & "|" & current_blood_d
```

3. Mother and Father are lookups on blood mix with mother or father ids

```
Mother's Blood Mix = 
VAR current_id = 'Sheet1'[ID]
VAR current_gen = 'Sheet1'[Generation]
VAR gen_value = 'Sheet1'[Blood mix]
VAR current_parent_id = 
    IF(LOWER(current_gen) = "1",current_id,'Sheet1'[Mother ID])
VAR result = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCT('Sheet1'[Blood mix]),
        FILTER(
            ALLNOBLANKROW('Sheet1'[ID]),
            'Sheet1'[ID] = current_parent_id
        ),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Sheet1')
    )
RETURN
    result
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this way (rather high resource consuming):

NEW COLUMN:

```
heritage_Father = PATH(Blood[ID],(Blood[FatherID]))
heritage_Mother = PATH(Blood[ID],(Blood[MotherID]))
Mancestor = LOOKUPVALUE(Blood[heritage_Mother],Blood[ID],Blood[FatherID]) &"|"& Blood[heritage_Mother]
Fancestor = LOOKUPVALUE(Blood[heritage_Father],Blood[ID],Blood[MotherID])&"|"&Blood[heritage_Father]
```

NEW MEASURE:

```
ASIA_check = 
VAR Table0 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", "0"&SELECTEDVALUE(Blood[Fancestor]) ),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( [Text] )+1
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, TokenCount )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( [Text], [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",VALUE([Word]))
VAR Table1 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", "0"&SELECTEDVALUE(Blood[Mancestor]) ),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( [Text] )+1
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, TokenCount )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( [Text], [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",VALUE([Word]))
RETURN
DIVIDe(
if(SELECTEDVALUE(Blood[Generation]) <> 1,
  calculate(sum(Blood[AsiaBlood]), FILTER(ALL(Blood), Blood[ID] in  Table0 || Blood[ID] in Table1)),0
),
(POWER(2, SELECTEDVALUE(Blood[Generation])-1)))

AFRICA_check = 
VAR Table0 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", "0"&SELECTEDVALUE(Blood[Fancestor]) ),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( [Text] )+1
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, TokenCount )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( [Text], [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",VALUE([Word]))
VAR Table1 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", "0"&SELECTEDVALUE(Blood[Mancestor]) ),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( [Text] )+1
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, TokenCount )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( [Text], [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",VALUE([Word]))
RETURN
DIVIDe(
if(SELECTEDVALUE(Blood[Generation]) <> 1,
  calculate(sum(Blood[AfricaBlood]), FILTER(ALL(Blood), Blood[ID] in  Table0 || Blood[ID] in Table1)),0
),
(POWER(2, SELECTEDVALUE(Blood[Generation])-1)))
```

[image]